# RecyclerView item animator problems

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

I am trying to remove items from a RecyclerView from my adapters onBindViewHolder. 
When I call this...

```
public void removeDropFromView(int position) {
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

...my animation shows, but it will not allow the adapter position to update (the new position 0 becomes position 1).

When I call this...

```
public void removeDropFromView(int position) {
    data.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

...the item is removed, the position of all my items are updated, but it completely skips the animation.

Some have said my troubles are coming from this not being possible in the onBindViewHolder, but I have tried all of this in the ViewHolder's onClick with the same results.

How can I get the animation to show, while also keeping all of the data in proper order?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting the data, get its viewholder, then call the setIsRecyclable(false) of the viewholder. Check [this](https://github.com/gjnidea/ToDoApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/gj/todoapp/fragments/ListFragment.java), line 102. It uses swipe to delete.